# Not inserting into database!

Tags: php, mysql, connection

Code not inserting into MySQL Database!?!?

Excerpt Register.php

```
$register = mysql_query("INSTER INTO users VALUE ('','$firstname','$lastname','$username','$password_db','$dob_db','$gender_db')");
                echo "Success!";
```

Connect.php

```
    <?php

    //connect

    $error = "Problem connecting to database. Please try again later.";

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die($error);
    mysql_select_db("upload") or die($error);

?>
```

It should all work. I don't get any errors when I use connect.php.

What's going on?

Also;

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: firstname in /opt/lampp/htdocs/imageupload/register.php on line 121
```

Please help?!

Comment: It looks like you are using global variables.
Read http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Comment: It's not the source of the problem but you should also read the notice. It's useful...

Answer (score 3):

The first line should read "INSERT INTO users VALUES", try that to start with.

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! Thank you :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Never assume your queries will succeed. At bare mininum put an `or die(mysql_error())` after each query call. Even if your SQL is completely valid, there's too many other reasons a query could fail to just blindly spit out "success!" while leaving a trail of destruction behind.